# Adaptador puente sin conexión

Tags: linux

Estoy usando virtualbox para virtualizar kali y hacer pruebas de red local, pero el punto esta en que no puedo configurarlo en **modo bridge**, sin NAT ,al seleccionar el modo bridge me sale sin ip, sin dns, sin ninguna configuración, configuro el archivo `/etc/network/interfaces` asigno la interfaz en modo dhcp, cambio los dns a telefonica no funciona, a los de google tampoco,configuro en modo static la interfaz eth0, y sigue igual.

Al querer hacer ping al dns de google me sale network unreachable, he buscado varias soluciones y sigue sin funcionar, por consiguiente al hacer ping a google sale que el host es desconocido, alguien que pueda darme una mano, por ahí leí que tal vez el firewall del router no permite hacer el modo bridge pues ese modo es como si otra computadora se conectara al router y se le asignara una ip , es como si fuera otra computadora mas de la red

Comment: Tu router asigna direcciones ip a traves de dhcp?

Comment: Para modo puente con salida a internet necesitas -por lo menos- dos interfaces de red.

Answer (score 0):

Bien cuando he trabajado virtualizando alguna maquina para hacer pruebas me aseguro de lo siguiente:

1. Configurar en modo puente asociandola a la interfaz de red adecuada (la que te brindara dhcp)
2. Verficar en el desplegable 'Avanzado' que este checkeada la opcion 'cable conectado'
3. Tener con dhcp automatico en la maquina virtual o en caso de ser linux tratar de capturar ip dinamica con 'dhclient nombre_interfaz'

   Muchas veces cuando configuras modo puente y lo asocias a  una interfaz inalambrica no existe comunicacion y por tanto no te dara dhcp. Si posees un cable de red mejor conecta via cable y siempre asegurate de marcar la opcion 'cable conectado' cuando configuras puente.

Tambien puedes intentar reinicialiar la mac de la interfaz de tu maquina virtual, eso lo configuras en el desplegable 'Avanzado' cuando confuguras puente.

Answer (score 0):

Primero si la interfaz de red está configurada como una NAT (Network Adress Translation) podrás tener conectividad con internet pero jamás con la red interna.

Si lo que deseas es configurar tu máquina virtual como una máquina más en la red, deberás de seleccionar en tipo de red "Conexión de Puente" y deberás seleccionar la tarjeta de red de tu host anfitrion (el que tiene virtual box instalada), si es windows sería algo así como "Conexión de red Cableada" o "Conexión inalámbrica", luego en la máquina virtual linux deberás correr el siguiente comando:

```
sudo su     #Solicita permisos de super usuario
dhclient -r #Libera cualquier configuración de ip automática
dhclient    #Realiza la peticion de ip al servidor DHCP
```

Para ver la dirección ip puedes usar

```
ifconfig
```

O bien para que sólo te diga la dirección de ip

```
ifconfig | egrep -e 'mtu|inet ' #El espacio del final es para que no tome direcciones IPV6
```

Éxitos.